# Find a closed form for the generating function for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, closed-form

The sequence: $0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$  The book gives the answer of $\frac{x^3}{1-x}$ but I'm not sure how to get this answer. I understand the generating function of this sequence will be $0 + 0x + 0x^2 + 1x^3 + 1x^4+1x^5 + 1x^6 + \ldots$ But I'm not sure how to put this in the closed form.

Comment: Yes, but what is the common ratio? x^3?

Comment: You skipped the $x^4$ term, not sure if that's intentional or not.

Comment: Another route is to start with the usual geometric series and subtract off the first three terms directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an index shift.

Since

$${1\over 1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

is generating for $1,1,1,\ldots$, and you want to make the first three into zeros, you multiply by $x^3$ resulting in an index shift:

$${x^3\over 1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+3}$$

So that you get the same sequence with three zeroes introduced at the beginning. If this is still not explicit enough, you can see this is:

> $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty x^n$$

By making the index shift $n+3\mapsto n$.

Comment: awesome, this makes sense now. I was missing understanding the index shift and translating the simple x^n to x^(n+3) Thank you so much for your quick response and thorough solution.

Comment: @MannfromReno No problem. Be sure to accept the answer (and upvote if you're feeling nice!) so people know the question is closed. :-)

Comment: Yup will do! just have to wait a few minutes until I'm allowed to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A more do-it-from-scratch approach:

Denote your sum $S$.  Then $x \cdot S = x^4 + x^5 + \cdots$.  Now subtracting $S-xS = x^3$.  Solve for $S$, and you're done.

This is exactly the same method used to express a repeating decimal as a fraction, and a variation of it will work for finding the generating function for any repeating sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the alternative approach!